# uninitialized constant Rack::Static (NameError) using rackup

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

i am unable to run my static file locally using `rackup config.ru`

```
> rackup config.ru                                                                                                                
simpli-web/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Rack::Static (NameError)
    from 
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:103:in `eval'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:103:in `new_from_string'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:94:in `load_file'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:64:in `parse_file'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:354:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:263:in `app'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:424:in `wrapped_app'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:326:in `block in start'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:382:in `handle_profiling'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:325:in `start'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/server.rb:182:in `start'
    from .rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/bin/rackup:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/cesario/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/rackup:25:in `load'
    from /Users/cesario/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/rackup:25:in `<main>'
```

below are my `config.ru` file

```
> ccat config.ru                                                                                                                  

use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

New error after adding `require 'rack/static''

```
> rackup config.ru                                                                                               P
[2023-06-16 10:48:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.8.1
[2023-06-16 10:48:54] INFO  ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30) [arm64-darwin21]
[2023-06-16 10:48:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=45618 port=9292
Rack::Lint::LintError: uppercase character in header name: Content-Type (Rack::Lint::LintError)


.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:653:in `block in check_headers'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:637:in `each'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:637:in `check_headers'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:73:in `response'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:35:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/show_exceptions.rb:27:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:43:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/content_length.rb:20:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/handler/webrick.rb:111:in `service'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'
::1 - - [16/Jun/2023:10:49:06 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 62691 0.0133
Rack::Lint::LintError: uppercase character in header name: Content-Type (Rack::Lint::LintError)
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:653:in `block in check_headers'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:637:in `each'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:637:in `check_headers'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:73:in `response'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/lint.rb:35:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/show_exceptions.rb:27:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:43:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.8/lib/rack/content_length.rb:20:in `call'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rackup-2.1.0/lib/rackup/handler/webrick.rb:111:in `service'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'
::1 - - [16/Jun/2023:10:49:07 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 60056 0.0100
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `require 'rack/static'` on top of your `config.ru`?

Comment: okay it runs now but encounter another error.

Comment: @HolgerJust see above the new error that pop up after i add  ` require `rack/static` `

Comment: And what would your intuition be for the cause of this error after reading the error message?

Comment: i changed it to lowercase and it worked. (: thank you!

Comment: I recommend avoiding static file service from the Ruby layer. Either use a reverse proxy to handle the static files (i.e., nginx) or an app server that supports static file service (i.e., iodine)... IMHO, a reverse proxy would be the better solution for most cases.